# How do you specify a custom file extension in an Electron app?

Tags: electron

I want to create a custom file type for my Electron app.  I want custom file icons and for the app to open when you double-click on the file.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [fileAssociations](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#PlatformSpecificBuildOptions-fileAssociations) option in electron-builder.  For example, in your package.json:

```
"build": {
  // ...
  "fileAssociations": [{
    "ext": "xyz",
    "name": "XYZ File",
    "role": "Editor"
  }]
}
```

Comment: How did you go about associating custom file icons?

Comment: @BrunoEly In your `build` directory, save files called *my_extension.icns* and *my_extension.ico*, where *my_extension* is your file extension.  Google for "icns generator" and "ico generator" for how to convert your icon to those file formats.